# Structural directive where I can get attribute value instead of computed boolean

Tags: angular

I know one can make [custom structural directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#ngIf).

```
<p *my-unless="someExpression">
```

However, the expression between the quotes is passed in computed with the resulting boolean value

```
@Input() set myUnless(condition: boolean) {
    console.log(condition);//either true, false, or undefined
}
```

How can I make it so I just get a raw string value so that if I did

```
<p *my-unless="some space delimted values">
```

I could do

```
@Input() set myUnless(theString: string) {
    console.log(theString);//=> theString == 'some space delimted values'
}
```

Ultimately, I am making a role-restricted directive in which the allowed roles are stated within the attribute value and I do the check within the directive component code like

```
 @Input() 
    set forRoles(allowedRoles: string) {
        let userTypes = allowedRoles.split(' ');
        if(~userTypes.indexOf(this.authenticatorService.getUserType())){
          this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        } else {
          this.viewContainer.clear();
        }
    }
```

Maybe structural directives are wrong for this kind of thing? It just feels that wrapper components everywhere I needed this would be overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using binded attributes, Angular expects a variable.

First example without binded attributes, you can use a string directly

```
<my-component someInput="some space delimted values"></my-component>
```

But if you use binding, you have to use single quotes.

```
<my-component [someInput]="'some space delimted values'"></my-component>
```

Structural directives behavior is the same as binded attributes, so you have to add single quotes :

```
<p *my-unless="'some space delimted values'">
```

Comment: thanks. I would initially go with your first suggestion then. The non-binded attribute. But, if I do that, I get `No provider for TemplateRef!` because its looking for a binded attribute? I guess, put another way, can I make a custom directive that is not bound?

Comment: I don't think so. Structural directives are handled like binded attributes.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
<p *my-unless="'some space delimted values'">
```

Comment: you know, I clearly dont understand this directive thing. So, laugh at me if Im wrong, but I thought when you put an expression like `something.length > 0` or whatever, it just *evaled* it and passed in the results. But now, Im just confused, it looks like it either *evals* it or just passes in the variable if its a string?

Comment: in my solution you pass a string 'some space delimted values', in your solution you pass variable some space delimted values which doesn't exist in context of directive

Comment: Thanks, I get that now :-)